# Why for every rational $p$ the level sets $\{ f \leq p \}$ and $\{ f \geq p \}$ are $\prod_{\xi+1}^0$ sets?

Tags: descriptive-set-theory, baire-category

$f$ is a real-valued baire class $\xi$ function if $\{ f < c \}$ and $\{ f >c \}$ are in $\sum_{\xi +1}^0$ for every $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

In the proof of [Proposition $5.2$](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.5724v2.pdf) page $24$, we have the following sentence:

> For every rational $p$ the level sets $\{ f \leq p \}$ and $\{ f \geq p \}$ are $\prod_{\xi+1}^0$ sets.

Why the statement above true? I think it follows by the definition of baire class $\xi$ function? Am I right?

Comment: I'm confused: why the vote to close as off-topic? This seems to be a reasonable question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're over-thinking this: the complement of a $\bf \Sigma^0_\theta$ set is $\bf \Pi^0_\theta$, and $\{f\le p\}=\mathbb{R}\setminus \{f>p\}$ etc.

Comment: so the statement followed due to the definition of baire class $\xi$ right?

Comment: @Idonknow Yes-ish. It depends which definition of Baire class you use. The one I'm familiar with is inductive, via pointwise limits of lower-class functions, in which case the level-set characterization of Baire class is a *theorem* (not a hard one).